# Get the names and values of the arguments

Tags: ruby

I wanted an instance method that creates a hash with the name of the arguments and their values.

I crafted this solution, but it's verbose.

```
class Foo
  def bar(a, b, c, d)
    params = self.method(:sum).parameters.map { |_, param| param }
    params_with_values = {}
    params.each do |param|
      params_with_values[param] = binding.local_variable_get(param)
    end
    # continue work with params_with_values
    ... 
  end
end
```

If I were used `local_variables` on the first line (or before any other local variables were defined), I could replace the first line like so:

```
class Foo
  def bar(a, b, c, d)
    params = local_variables
    params_with_values = {}
    params.each do |param|
      params_with_values[param] = binding.local_variable_get(param)
    end
    # continue work with params_with_values
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there a more convenient, concise, or idiomatic way?

The problem I envision solving is that I can iterate on the resulting `params` hash inside the method (I do not want to return the `params` hash in my application).  Also, I could simply assign the hash literal to the local variable params:

```
params = {a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d}
```

but, I'd envisioned being able to define this method dynamically, so I would not be able to simply type the hash inside `Foo#bar`.

Comment: "If I were careful to call `local_variables` on the first line" makes no sense to me.  From that point on, I don't understand what's being asked.

Comment: I meant that as long as I used `local_variables` before defining any other variables, then I could rely on `local_variables` holding only the method parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your `local_variables`, you can refactor your code to:

```
class Foo
  def bar(a, b, c, d)
    local_variables.to_enum.with_object({}) do |k, h|
      h[k] = binding.local_variable_get(k)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I was not familiar with `.to_enum.with_object({})`.  Unless another answer can be provided, I think this is the most concise way to generate the hash in question. Thanks for the answer, and also thanks for cleaning up my question. It was nearly closed for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an idiomatic way to do this because local variables in a method are private in the scope of the method—not just technically, but also by convention. The rest of the program shouldn't care what those variables are called—exposing implementation details like that is very *un*idiomatic.

That said, as usual the least clever solution is probably best:

```
def bar(a, b, c, d)
  { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d }
end
```

Comment: That makes sense. Well stated. Please see my edit with details on the background of the problem.  Can you offer any other advice?